# Cypress CI vsts not finding binary

Tags: cypress, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Could you please give me some advise on how to deal with this issue.

Build Pipeline

```
npm install
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^3.4.1"
  }
```

Release

Powershell command

```
npm ./node_modules/.bin/Cypress run

The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.

2019-10-07T18:04:59.5720120Z We expected the binary to be installed here:
```

There are some examples on how to cache ~/.npm but nothing seems to work so far. Examples on how to include cypress.io in your vsts are at the building stage and not after release.

Comment: Did your error have any update? Is my answer helpful for your question?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error log, it has provided a solution about this. You should run the cypress install command first and then the error will be fixed.

[image]

As my test, since I don't have a cypress.json file, so I need run the open command to 
automatic generated get the json file and project sample.
Then the open command run as expected.
[image: ![enter image description here]

But because I run the open command in interactive mode and I don't have the cypress.json file in my artifacts, the taks finally failed.

So if you have cypress.json in your repo or artifacts, you just need to add

```
.\cypress install
```

in your powershell command.

And if not, you can add the related json file and folder to your repo or artifacts and then the run command will work as your expected.