# The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, continuous-integration, pipeline, cypress

Hello everyone i'm new with azure devops CI  and  i'm trying to reduice my pipeline build time  by caching node_modules between jobs ,but i got this error that i can't resolve. i'm using cypress for  testing.
Here is my azure pipeline

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | “$(Agent.OS)” | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/package-lock.json'
    path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/node_modules'
    cacheHitVar: 'CacheRestored'

- script: npm install
  displayName: 'npm install '
  condition: ne(variables['CacheRestored'], 'true')
  
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run scripts'
  continueOnError: false  
  displayName: 'Npm run test'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish Artifact: cypress-and-azure-devops Screenshots"
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: cypress/screenshots
    ArtifactName: CypressAndAzureDevopsTestRunScreenshots
  condition: failed()

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Publish Artifact: cypress-and-azure-devops Videos "
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: cypress/videos
    ArtifactName: CypressAndAzureDevopsTestRunVideos
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: "Publish Test Results"
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
    testResultsFiles: "**/cypress-and-azure-devops-*.xml"
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get the error message similar to the following?

```
The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.
We expected the binary to be installed here: /xxx/.cache/Cypress/4.8.0/Cypress/Cypress
Reasons it may be missing:
- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /xxx/.cache/Cypress
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: /root/.cache/Cypress
Properly caching the binary will fix this error and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress.
Alternatively, you can run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.
```

If so, according to the error log, it provides a workaround to this problem. You can try to run the cypress install command again to fix the problem. Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275454/cypress-ci-vsts-not-finding-binary) you can refer to.

In addition, the quotation mark of `“$(Agent.OS)”` should be like `"$(Agent.OS)"`. Or you can choose to run the jobs in [self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) agent, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , actually i added a step that install cypress again and it resolved the problem.

Comment: Done, have a nice day too :)