# Azure Devops Pipeline fails in one subscription but works in another

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Bit of an odd one...

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline YAML file that works absolutely fine, 100% of the time, when running under one subscription, but fails 100% of the time in another.  The file is closed-source, so can't share it unfortunately - but it isn't doing anything crazy.  It installs dependencies, runs tests and produces a build artefact. The failure always happens at the same point, with an error message regarding caching stuff from npm.

As far as I can tell both subscriptions have the same setup with regards to build agents etc.

The error in question is the same as here: [The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356601/the-cypress-npm-package-is-installed-but-the-cypress-binary-is-missing) although I stress the pipeline works perfectly in one subscription, but not in another (and there are zero differences between the two codebases).

I appreciate this is somewhat vague, but any potential pointers/help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do these builds run on [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents) or [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)?

Comment: This looks like an issue with [caching Cypress artifacts](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/caching-node-modules-and-cypress-installation-in-an-azure-devops-pipeline-3f7a2e07960b). Have you checked if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58284070/10805761) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703115/10805761) help?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevera - Both agents are Microsoft hosted and the error is *definitely* that Cypress  caching one (and I have a suitable workaround for that).  The real problem is that I’m getting different results in two pipelines which, as far as I can tell, are 100% identical. One repo is a fork of the other and the codebases are identical.

Comment: Hi Ben, do you have conditional steps in your pipeline? Please check the logs to make sure the two pipelines run the same steps. And may I know the meaning of "subscription" mentioned in your question?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT - no, there are no conditional statements.

Subscription: Azure DevOps subscription.  The code is in two repos one owned by me, one by another developer.  We both have paid Azure DevOps subscriptions with paid build agents for running pipelines (we're not using the free stuff).

The vm image used in the pipeline is ubuntu-latest

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm not sure about the meaning of Azure DevOps subscription(we don't have such name, may you are referring to PAT or service connection?). Does it refer to Azure Subscription?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT yeah, I guess it falls under Azure subscription.  I have an Azure subscription with paid build agents to run pipelines in devops.  Another developer has an Azure subscription with paid build agents to run pipelines devops.  When I run the pipeline in my Azure sub it works 100% of the time, when it runs in the other developer's Azure sub it fails 100% of the time. The code and pipeline is exactly the same.  One is a fork of the other and they are identical in every way.

Comment: Maybe the permissions assigned to you and your colleague are different, he may have to ask Admin to get higher permission level.